# The basic representation of $LU(1)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, loop-groups

Let $H = L^2(U(1),\mathbb{C})$. The "basic" irreducible projective level 1 representation $\mathcal{H}$ of the loop group $LU(1)$ has underlying Hilbert space isomorphic to $\smash{\hat{\bigwedge}}^\bullet(H \oplus \bar{H}^-) \cong \hat{\bigoplus}_{k\geq 0} \bigwedge^k(H\oplus \bar{H}^-)$. This is constructed e.g. in Pressley–Segal.

Is there an explicit way to describe the projective $LU(1)$-action on this representation? Namely, given $\gamma : S^1 \to U(1)$ how does $\gamma$ explicitly act on an element of $\mathcal{H}$?

(There is an "obvious" action of $LU(1)$ on $\mathcal{H}$ where $\gamma$ just acts on the individual elements in an exterior power $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge \dotsm \wedge v_n$. This seems to give the correct character, but it's not obvious that this action needs to be projective.)